# What is one word or phrase to say "I will set an object or I will remove the object's placeholder"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I'm trying to name a method in a programming language and can't figure out what it should be called.

I'm looking for a single word or phrase that means "If you give me an object I will place it on its placeholder, if you give me nothing, I will remove its placeholder and any object that was on its placeholder"

What I have tried so far but doesn't really make the sense I need it too is "set or remove" so the method reads like

```
setOrRemove:object;
```

Comment: For Programming in general, a more descriptive name is better than a easier one, especially since you have IDE's that let you auto fill in the names.

Comment: @Link that's why I am asking for a word or phrase, and I'm writing Objective-C, which is known to be very verbose. Still have the problem though :D

Comment: Your terminology suggests that you do not have a very good grasp on the mechanics of Objective-C.

Comment: "Dismiss" probably already has other meanings in your field so I'll just suggest it as a comment, but a dismissed employee is sometimes replaced and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

*Toggle* is a standard term for switching back and forth between opposite conditions, from *toggle switch*.

Comment: The issue with `toggle` is that it generally means to switch between true and false and depends on the current state. In my method, you can change the value, or you can pass nothing to remove the previously set value from existence.

Answer (score 1):

just `replace` ? if you give me nothing, i will replace the placeholder with nothing. if you give me an object, I will replace the placeholder with the object. Perhaps `replacePlaceholder`.